# Merge page with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, pages

This may be a weird scenario, but...I have a custom post type called Resources. When visiting /resources/ I get the archive as expected. What I want is a text describing this post type. Therefore I've made a page with the exact name and path. If I now go to /resources/ I still get the archive page, which is good. So, I created a custom template (archive-resources.php) and from there I searched pages with the same path and then I find my page and is able to write out the text before listing the archive.

What I want to know is that, is this a good way to solve my problem? if not, how can I make it better?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need/want to introduce a static Page into this scenario at all. Is there any problem with merely using `archive-resources.php` to display the "Resources" archive index, with descriptive text?

Comment: Well the problem is that you can't set a description for a post type. I'm not going to hard code it in the template for obvious reasons.

Comment: What are the "obvious reasons" for not hard-coding a *custom post-type specific* description into a *custom post-type specific* template file?

Comment: First, my site is multilingual, long texts like that shouldn't be translated that way. Second, I'm not the editor and I'm pretty sure the easiest way for the editor to change that text is to do it in the admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with using `archive-$cpt_name.php` as your default archive page for the custom post type. That would be the correct way to go about doing it. Although there are many different methods to do it, I think you are on the right track to the best way.